# Slash(/) in url returns 500 server error, how to redirect it?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have a html site, where i used the following code to lose .html from urls. But if added a slash to the url it returns 500 internal server error. It doesnt even redirect to the custom 404 page.

What i want is either force the slash on every url, or if anyone tries, the slash urls to be redirected to non slash urls. I am bit puzzled how its going on.

**Here is how my htaccess looks like now**

```
# mod_rewrite starts here

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /not-found-page.html

Redirect 307 /directions (link replaced)
Redirect 307 /yelp-reviews (link replaced)
Redirect 307 /google-reviews (link replaced)
Redirect 307 /probate-attorney-location (link replaced)

# 6G FIREWALL/BLACKLIST
# @ https://perishablepress.com/6g/

# 6G:[QUERY STRING]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (eval\() [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:)(.*)(;) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode)(.*)(\() [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)(.*)script(.*)(>|%3) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\.\.|\.\./|~|`|<|>|\|) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|etc/passwd|self/environ) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (thumbs?(_editor|open)?|tim(thumb)?)\.php [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\'|\")(.*)(drop|insert|md5|select|union) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(connect|debug|move|put|trace|track) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REFERRER]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (semalt.com|todaperfeita) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REQUEST STRING]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)([a-z0-9]{2000,})
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(https?|ftp|php):/
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(base64_encode)(.*)(\()
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(=\\\'|=\\%27|/\\\'/?)\.
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(\$(\&)?|\*|\"|\.|,|&|&amp;?)/?$
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\\\"\\\")
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(~|`|<|>|:|;|,|%|\\|\{|\}|\[|\]|\|)
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(=|\$&|_mm|cgi-|muieblack)
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(&pws=0|_vti_|\(null\)|\{\$itemURL\}|echo(.*)kae|etc/passwd|eval\(|self/environ)
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)\.(aspx?|bash|bak?|cfg|cgi|dll|exe|git|hg|ini|jsp|log|mdb|out|sql|svn|swp|tar|rar|rdf)$
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(^$|(wp-)?config|mobiquo|phpinfo|shell|sqlpatch|thumb|thumb_editor|thumbopen|timthumb|webshell)\.php
</IfModule>

# 6G:[USER AGENT]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) bad_bot
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (archive.org|binlar|casper|checkpriv|choppy|clshttp|cmsworld|diavol|dotbot|extract|feedfinder|flicky|g00g1e|harvest|heritrix|httrack|kmccrew|loader|miner|nikto|nutch|planetwork|postrank|purebot|pycurl|python|seekerspider|siclab|skygrid|sqlmap|sucker|turnit|vikspider|winhttp|xxxyy|youda|zmeu|zune) bad_bot

    # Apache < 2.3
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from env=bad_bot
    </IfModule>

    # Apache >= 2.3
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <RequireAll>
            Require all Granted
            Require not env bad_bot
        </RequireAll>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `/` is a slash. `\\` is a backslash.

Comment: Hi that's interesting, perhaps rewrite debugging would be of interest https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteLog

Comment: Thanks D. Pardal, fixed it. I was thinking nothing while writing :(

Comment: IronMan im clueless about htaccess rules. I will try to go through that, im afraid that would be too much to learn in a day . :(